# Can I ask a for a "technical quality control" on answers of mine? Where do I ask for that?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've received 2 downvotes on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/608801/380067) answer of mine. None of the two users who casted the downvote bothered to explain why they downvoted it.

You can judge this better than me, but the answer is *in my opinion* clear and well explained, so *I'm assuming* that whoever downvoted it must have done it because it's technically wrong somewhere.

if there's something wrong in that answer (altough it still doesn't seem to me), I'd like to understand what it is.

I'd like to know for this and for further cases:

1. If I can ask for a "technical quality control" on main site, perhaps in the form of:

> Is it technically wrong to state that:
>
> [answer]
>
> if someone asked:
>
> [question]

2. If not, if I can ask for it on meta, perhaps in the form of:

> What's wrong with this answer:
>
> [answer]
>
> given to this question?
>
> [question]

Comment: I think this service is provided by the community in general. Not everyone leaves a comment when they down vote. Ask for feedback from those who do in the comments. Otherwise try the chat room perhaps ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yes, maybe asking in the chat is the best solution

Comment: Even if you know a downvote doesn't mean the world, we all know it doesn't feel nice. Look at it this way: unless an answer is really bad and has obvious issues, a downvote without an explanation usually isn' t the best founded one. It also simply doesn't give the poster the opportunity to either explain or improve. Easy to say, but not really worth worrying a lot about it. We've all been there.

Comment: @JacobVlijm It's also most about learning whether I'm doing something wrong or not, and that's why I'd like to ask about that answer, altough the more I'm thinking about this the more I'm convinced that simply those downvotes were casted randomly. Altough it was a bit strange, since they were casted almost sequentially after an edit (if I recall well). I almost never received a downvote (of course it happened) but most of all I never received two downvote in a row like this time, so I took it as a sign of a severe issue. I'm almost convinced that it has just been a coincidence.

Comment: Just to make you feel better: got a downvote on this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/461948/72216 I think, no, I am absolutely positive there is nothing wrong with it :). Like there is nothing wrong with your answer.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, nothing wrong with your answer either, actually is a very good answer (upvoted)

Comment: Thanks :)  Probably someone is bored and needs to push the button every now and then :).